# How do you access/configure summaries/snippets in Django Haystack

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I'm working on getting django-haystack set up on my site, and am trying to have snippets in my search results roughly like so:

> **Title of result one about *Wikis***
>  ...this special thing about *wiki* values is that...I always use a *wiki* when I walk...snippet value three talks about *wikis* too...and here's another snippet value
>   about *wikis*.

I know there's a template tag that uses Haystack code to do the the highlighting, but the snippets it generates are pretty limited:

- they always start with the query word
- there's only one snippet value
- they don't support asterisk queries
- and other stuff?

Is there a way to use the Solr backend to generate proper snippets as shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom line is that the Solr highlighting can't really be used by Haystack in a flexible way. I spoke to the main developer for Haystack on IRC, and he said basically, if I want to have the kind of highlighting I'm looking for, the only way to get it is to extend the Solr backend that Haystack uses.

I dabbled in that for about half a day, but couldn't get Haystack to recognize my custom back end. Haystack has some magic backend loading code that just wasn't working with me.

Consequently, I've switched over to [sunburnt](https://github.com/tow/sunburnt), which provides a lighter-weight and more extensible wrapper around Solr. I'm hoping it will fare better.

Comment: Haystack doesn't have any magic loading code for backends. I've written a couple and it's fairly straightforward. You take the base class, extend it, then invoke it just like every other thing in Python.

Comment: Also, particular query terms are VERY easy to add to Haystack when it comes to Solr. If you dabbled in it for half a day and couldn't get it to work you were taking the wrong approach.

Comment: Yeah, I got that impression. I forget the details now, but it could be my python-fu isn't quite good enough to follow all of the useful things Haystack provides. Frustrating at the time though.

Answer (score 0):

```
from haystack.utils import Highlighter
my_text = 'This is a sample block that would be more meaningful in real life.'
my_query = 'block meaningful'
highlight = Highlighter(my_query)
highlight.highlight(my_text)
```

http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/highlighting.html

Comment: Thanks @Willian. I updated the question above, since the highlighter class you're demoing here is pretty limited.